# Storing DateTime consistently on server and client

Tags: c#, javascript, entity-framework, date

While developing an app, I've faced the problem of time consistency between the client and the server. Let me describe the application first. Entity framework ORM (MS SQL server is used as database engine) is used (Code First approach). On the client page I have a simple form which accepts date and time. When I want to submit the form and send the data the next steps occur:

- User presses Submit(the date was stored as a javascript date object thus with current user time zone)
- An object that contains all form data to send(including that date and time) is serialized into JSON. what `JSON.Stringify` does is that it converts a date object into a string representation of that date, but in **UTC** format. That date is stored in the database.
- When the user requests this data, a JSON string is returned; however the server returns a date in normal format (not UTC). JSON.parse DOES NOT convert a string that represents a date into a javascript object. So when I parse a date I get the wrong value.

Example: Suppose the user entered 05/25/2014 22:20:00 and its time zone offset is GMT +3. Now the user-submitted form date will be converted to UTC: 05/25/2014 19:20:00, and this will be saved into the DB. User then requests the data and gets the wrong date and time - 19:20:00.

I realize that I can achieve correct handling via manual parsing of the date on the client side. But is there any way to provide consistency of dates by:

- telling EF to treat date as UTC and return it in UTC format
- telling JSON deserializer to parse date

I think this will provide date consistency. Of course, I'd like to store dates in UTC - that's the main idea.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a `DateTime` combined with the `JSON.parse` issue rather than from EF.

Since you know you're storing the date in the DB as UTC, and we know that the web server converts `DateTimes`into the "local" kind of time zone automatically when retrieved, perhaps you could convert the `DateTime` back into UTC before returning it as a JSON string.

```
var dateTimeToReturn = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(theDateTimeRetrievedFromTheDB, TimeZoneInfo.Local)).ToString(); // or one of the other string conversion methods/formatting provided by DateTime, in the form you want displayed to the user
```

then return `dateTimeToReturn` as the string you want displayed, and just have the view code display it as is without parsing it.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you, but this way we'll render date in timezone server was set up with, not the one set up on client machine. So It seems to me this should be done on client. But again, this is routine manual work.